# VBA Internet Explorer Automation issue

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, click, getelementbyid

I try to make a VBA macro that will

1. Activate an open internet page
2. Enter text in a field
3. Click on a button
4. click on a link in the result

My code is the following **for part 1** and it works

```
    AppTitle = "Search Outbound Batches"
        AppActivate AppTitle     
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")    
    For i = 0 To 25    
        strName = ""      
        On Error Resume Next      
        strName = oApp.Windows(i).document.Url
If InStr(strName, "http://...") Then
                    Set oIE = oApp.Windows(i)          
            Exit For            
        End If
    Next
```

**For part 2** I try this but it's nor working : nothing is entered

```
Set imputtext = oIE.document.getElementsByName("SBatchNumber")
  inputtext.Value = "3424"
```

**Result of the inspection Element on the webpage:**

[image]

**For part 3** I tried this but not working neither

```
    Set tags = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("button")
For Each tagx In tags
  If tagx.innerText = "Go" Then
     tagx.Click
     Exit For
  End If
Next
```

**This is the inspection detail:**

[image: Result of the inspection Element on the webpage]

**For part 4** this but not working neither

```
 Set Batch = oIE.document.All("N3:BatchNumber:0")
    Batch.Click
```

[image: Result of the inspection Element on the webpage]

I send you also a printscreen of the web page in order you have a better understanding:

[image: Printscreen of the webpage]

Could you please help me to solve all these issues ?
Thanks a lot,
Oliver

Comment: Getelementsbyname returns a collection. Not a single node. You need to index into that collection with the correct index assuming name selector is correct.

Comment: Overall I would suggest reviewing existing answers using queryselector and attribute selectors and better target your nodes, without need for loops and innertext, using attribute selectors.

Comment: Please, try to make one single question, not 3, in each post.

Comment: I agree with the suggestion given by the QHarr about locating the correct element. Further, you can notice in the HTML code that each element you are trying to automate has events attached to it. Like Onclick, Onchange, OnKeyPress, OnKeyUp. I suggest you after setting the value for each element or after performing the clicking action, try to dispatch those events that may help you to get the desire results.